# Galactic or Extra-galactic Cosmic Rays?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, cosmology, astrophysics, cosmic-rays

If we want to show whether or not a specific Cosmic Ray particle is confined to our galaxy we must use the Larmor radius (relativistic version),

$$r = \gamma \, \frac{ m  c}{q B}$$

Considering a $10^{14}$ eV proton and assuming the galactic magnetic field strength is $10^{-11}$ T, show that the particle is confined to the Milky Way (radius $15$ kpc).

How can we use the Larmor radius to prove that the particle is in fact confined to the Milky Way?

Attempt:

$$r = \frac{p}{qB}, \,\,\,\,\, p=\gamma mc$$
Therefore
   $$r=\frac{E}{cqB}$$
and substituting values in yields
   $$r = \frac{10^{14}}{(3\times10^8)(1.6\times10^{-19})(10^{-11})}$$
such that
   $$r \sim10^{36} \,\,\,\,\text{(meters?)}$$

Comment: $10^{36}$ meters is pretty far. Are you sure your units work out right?

Comment: I think if should convert the Energy from eV to Joules, which instead returns a value of $10^{17}$ meters, which is approximately 1 parsec?

Comment: And how large is a galaxy compared to a parsec?

Comment: Actually $E/q=10^{14}$V, the $B\sim \frac{Vs}{m^2}$, then $r$ is in meter after throwing $1.6\cdot 10^{-19}$ out of the right side of the equation.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/593248/59023

Answer (score 0):

A proton with an energy of 100 TeV (= $10^{14}$ eV) has a [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) of ~$10^{5}$ and a [cyclotron frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron_resonance) of ~$10^{-9}$ Hz for a 0.01 nT magnetic field.  The proton's speed is ~0.999999999956 times the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light).

Thus, this example [cosmic ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray) proton would have a [gyroradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroradius) of ~3 x $10^{13}$ m or ~223 AU ([astronomical unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit)).

> How can we use the Larmor radius to prove that the particle is in fact confined to the Milky Way?

A single [light year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-year) is nearly $10^{16}$ m (~63,200 AU) or nearly 1000 times larger than the gyroradius of our example proton.  The [Milky Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way) is upwards of 100,000 light years across, i.e., nearly 100 million times the gyroradius of the example proton.